# Laravel Voyager menu is not updating

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, voyager

I am using a laravel voyager package and there is a need to update the menu. Despite updating their admin_menu.vue in the component folder, the changes are not being reflected. Also, I run below command :

```
php artisan cache:clear
npm update 
npm run watch-poll
```

[link of voyager package](https://github.com/thedevdojo/voyager)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove these things from the side menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58042991/how-can-i-remove-these-things-from-the-side-menu)

Comment: As I mentioned earlier I already cleared cache. So it's not a duplicate & unfortunately you didn't even read my question completely

Comment: Did you find a fix for this in the end?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when using the voyager json menu `menu('admin', '_json')` after inserting menu_items records directly into database, the changes where not reflecting. The solution was to run

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: Works for me, but why is this behavior

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by updating `permission_role` table manually.

You can look up all the missing permissions in `permissions` table and user id you want to update menu for in the `users` table. After that you can update `permission_role` correctly.